# How do I accept iText license

Tags: java, itext

I wanted to try to use iText libraries so I got a free license. In the process the directions say to add the itextlicensekey.jar to my class path which I did and then run LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile("path/to/itextkey.xml"). When I did it I got a no ClassDefFoundError. is there something I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You're missing the iText dependencies. In this case, [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/).

Comment: also, probably best to use maven or gradle to manage your dependencies